# Android Studio, запретить вызов Toast поверх другого

Tags: java, android-studio, android-toast

У меня есть метод, который вызывает `Toast` и отображает какую-то строку, но если быстро его вызывать, то сообщения накладываются поверх друг друга, а не выходят друг за другом. Закончился один `Toast`, вышел другой и т.д. *(так нужно мне)*

Вот код метода:

```
public static void showInformation(String text) {
    if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel();
    }
    toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Подскажите, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Убрал условие и всё заработало...

```
public static void showInformation(String text) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```